# Zend Framework 2 inserting into database works fine but still iam getting an error

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-framework2, zend-db, zend-db-table

Here is my model code below,

```
public function insertme()
{
    $sel = new Sql($this->adapter);
    $s = $sel->insert('users');
    $data = array(
            'fname'=>'fisdsds',
            'lname'=>'sdsdsdme',
            'email'=>'sdsdsds',
            'pword'=>'dsdsds'

    );
    $s->values($data);
    $statement = $sel->prepareStatementForSqlObject($s);
    $comments = $statement->execute();      
    $resultset = new ResultSet();
    $resultset->initialize($comments);
    $result = $resultset->toArray();
    //print_R($result);
    return $result;

}
```

it is inserting data into database table `users` but iam also getting an error `SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error` what could be the problem?

Comment: @TomPHP how can it be duplicate?this is `insert` query that is `update` query ......

Comment: possibly due to an insert NOT returing a restult set..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no need to try and make a ResultSet from an insert, it's not going to give you back any resultset data.

```
public function insertme()
{
    $sel = new Sql($this->adapter);
    $s = $sel->insert('users');
    $data = array(
            'fname'=>'fisdsds',
            'lname'=>'sdsdsdme',
            'email'=>'sdsdsds',
            'pword'=>'dsdsds'

    );
    $s->values($data);
    $statement = $sel->prepareStatementForSqlObject($s);
    $result= $statement->execute();      
    //print_R($result);

    return $result;
}
```